# Excluding subdirectory from gulp-watch throwing type error

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm running the following watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    gulp.watch('./ui/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('./js/*.js', '!./js/vendor/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.html', ['html']);

});
```

But it seems to throw the following error?...

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'mark' of !./js/vendor/*.js at new Gaze
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need brackets around the paths if you want to specify multiple. Try the following for your second watch:

```
gulp.watch(['./js/*.js', '!./js/vendor/*.js'], ['scripts']);
```

`gulp.watch` handles the file argument the same as [`vinyl-fs`](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs#usage). So you can use all the features specified in their documentation in `gulp.watch` as well.

Answer (score 1):

the second parameter of the watch must declare as array

```
gulp.watch('src...', ['taskname', ......];
```